# Mousewheel event not detaching on window resize

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, window-resize

I have a mouseswheel function that moves the position of the element a certain length, and it works, except it duplicates the event on window resize. Not sure why. Basically what happens is when I try to mouse-scroll after resizing the window, it fires the event multiple times depending on how many times I resized the window, thus moving the position much further.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var scrollLength = 100;
    this_main.on('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            caseSliderContainer.css({'left': caseSliderContainer.position().left - scrollLength});
        }else{
            caseSliderContainer.css({'left': caseSliderContainer.position().left + scrollLength});
        }

        //prevent page fom scrolling
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
this_main.unbind('mousewheel'); //unbind the event
this_main.on('mousewheel', function(e)
.
.
.
```

So on every resize it will unbind the function and rebind it again, so you will not have replication

Comment: Can you tell me what the difference of using 'off' for unbind would be?

Comment: Yep sometimes the complicated problems have a simple answer :), don't forget to mark this as an answer :P.

off will do the same as unbind, off doesn't work with jquery 1.6 and earlier, you can use off too, if you have the latest jquery library.

But you should do it immediately before on function so that there is no change of replication